# apt-get install does not work properly

Tags: apt

`apt-get install` command in the terminal does not work and says

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package
```

I have tried updating the repositories and even tried changing the `sources.list` file in `/etc/apt/` folder but it still repeats the same.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and which package are you looking for? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-get update`?

Comment: Did you use a package after *apt-get install* command? Like *apt-get install php*?

Answer (score 0):

If you have broken packages try `apt-get -f` to fix it and try add some repository that will help apt to find your packages.
And also check `apt-cache` command ,It will helps you.

Comment: There are no broken packages, that would lead to a different message. Also, your other advices are not really helpful because a newbie would not understand what you mean. Please elaborate your answer and improve its quality by adding clear descriptions of how to do something and why. You should read http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer to learn how to write better answers.